# unable to call upon resources (particularly a string array) - java / android

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have created a string array, but am unable to access it in my java. I'm pretty new to java, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is part of an android app that will use the string array for captions below a bunch of pictures in a series.

Here's what I have. If I comment out these two lines it still runs:

```
Resources res=getResources();
String[] captionArray=res.getStringArray(R.array.chapter0captions);
```

This is part of a class that is used for storing the images and captions i wish to open using the Activities that are my menus (not sure if i explained that well...) I can't figure out what is wrong with those two lines, but I really would like to call upon my array instead of having to copy paste under each part of the switch-case code. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Resources;

public class PositionStorage extends Application {
    public static int imageToOpen;
    public static String captionToOpen;
    public static String imageToOpenString;
    Resources res=getResources();
    String[] captionArray=res.getStringArray(R.array.chapter0captions);
public void storeTheString(int pos){
        int imageNumber=pos+1;
     switch (imageNumber) {
        case 1:
            imageToOpen=0x7f020005;
             captionToOpen=captionArray[pos];
            break;
        case 2:
            imageToOpen=0x7f020010; 
            captionToOpen=captionArray[pos];
            break;
        case 3:
            imageToOpen=0x7f02001b;
            captionToOpen=captionArray[pos];
            break;
```

Comment: What is the error if you put those two? And what's in R.array.chapter0captions? Can you put what's in R.array.chapter0captions as part of the question?

Comment: What is the error you get when you uncomment the code where you access the string array? It could be that R.array.chapter0captions is not defined. If you're sure a resource with this name exists, try cleaning and rebuilding your project. Sometimes that is necessary for the resource file to get fully updated.

Comment: R.array.chapter0captions   was defined in my strings.xml file. It is a very long string-array, but the basic layout is....   <string-array name="chapter0captions">
   <item>FIG. 1</item> <item>FIG. 2</item></string-array>

Comment: And the error I get is a force quit when I run the app in the emulator....I might need some help figuring out how to use the debugger....logcat says GC_Explicit freed ***

Comment: debugger says this......                                         Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
 PositionStorage(ContextWrapper).getResources() line: 80 
 PositionStorage.<init>() line: 10 
 Chapter0Menu.onListItemClick(ListView, View, int, long) line: 32 
 ListActivity$2.onItemClick(AdapterView, View, int, long) line: 321 
 ListView(AdapterView).performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 284 
 ListView.performItemClick(View, int, long) line: 3382 
 AbsListView$PerformClick.run() line: 1696  
 .......it goes on, but does that help??

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare String array into the string.xml file.Instead declare the string array in the arrays.xml under the values folder.

the Structure is

> > res>>values>>arrays.xml

In the arrays.xnl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string-array name="xxxarray">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>thre</item>
</string-array>
```

in your activity

```
String[] arrayvalues=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.xxxarray);
```

if you declare the array in the string.xml then the system treats that as the String.

Comment: this did not work, and I don't think it makes a difference because in my R.java file it showed up under R.array.chapter0captions regardless of the xml file it was written in